# validation with a CustomValidator and JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have used a `customfieldvalidator` for checking the length of username. The length checking is done from a JavaScript function and I have used a `validatorcalloutextender` to display the error message. It is not working properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function username_validate(src, args) {
        args.isValid = args.Value.length >= 3;
    }
</script>

<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvTxtUserName" runat="server" 
    ValidationGroup="vgroup" ControlToValidate="txtUserName" 
    ErrorMessage="Minimum 3 characters Required" Text="*" 
    SetFocusOnError="false" 
    ClientValidationFunction="username_validate"></asp:CustomValidator>

<cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender1" 
     runat="server" Enabled="true" TargetControlID="cvTxtUserName">
</cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Sure, what's the problem? Are you getting an error? You may want to try a `RegexValidator` for something this simple.

Comment: What is it doing/not doing? Have you verified that args.Value is what you want to be validating on?

Answer (score 0):

You have a casing problem and need "IsValid" rather than "isValid". On top of that you probably also need a RequiredFieldValidator in case the field is left empty.

So your java script should be

`function username_validate(src, args) {
        args.IsValid = args.Value.length >= 3;
    }`

I don't think the validation is fired if the text box is empty, so use a regular asp.net RequiredFieldValidator to cover that case. And besides you should always combine client side validation with server side validation since client validation can be circumvented.